# Acer 5552 black screen

Tags: laptop, boot, bios

My son's ACER 5552 laptop is not booting properly.   Press the power switch and the power button light comes on but nothing else happens.

I downloaded the most recent bios onto a usb stick and went through the routine of remove battery, remove power cable, hold FN ESC down, insert power cable, switch power on which I understand should update the bios.  Sounds indicated that the fan was on, hd was spinning and the DVD drive made noises but nothing appeared on the screen.

I connected the vga socket to my tv as a screen check and nothing appeared.
I removed the CMOS battery and then replaced it but that made no difference either.

Comment: Does the machine beep when you boot it up? If so, check the beep code against the BIOS manufacturer. Can you confirm you can see the BIOS? If so, it means the issue isn't the screen, but the OS appears to be corrupted/faulty/broken. Try the repair disc

Comment: No beeps doesnt respond to disc in dvd drive.  I dont think I have a screen problem rather that the bios never seems to take effect.  I have put the latest bios files on the root directory of a sub stick but when following the prescribed process to install the bios at switch on time it doesnt seem to get read.

Comment: If you make a change to the BIOS (any change) and then reboot, does it remember your changes? Can you also confirm that all the connections (which you have access too) are plugged in well.

Comment: Ive had the panel off that gives access to the memory sticks cmos battery etc, I'll take the whole of the back off to check more connections.  So far I dont think any changes have been made to the bios because the screen has always remained blank, perhaps someone can confirm how to change the bios from the Fn Esc 'dead' start.

Comment: Same problem here... Acer confirms itself as the king of laptop lowbrow.

Answer (score 2):

Might be a bit old topic but...
I had the same issues with same model

FN + ESC did not work.

My solution

1) Prepare a usb stick with latest bios

Download it from [acer site](http://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/BIOS/BIOS/BIOS_Acer_2.14_A_A.zip?acerid=634483774426848318&Step1=NOTEBOOK&Step2=ASPIRE&Step3=ASPIRE%205552&OS=ALL&LC=el&BC=ACER&SC=EMEA_14)

Copy the fd and flashit.exe from dos folder to root of usb stick

Rename XEWxx214.fd to BIOS.FD or zg5ia32.fd I had it with both names ;)

2) Open back cover remove battery and RAM.
   Under Ram there are two solder's close to each other, short circuit them with a screw driver
   While shorted these contacts press Power button and keep it short circuited for a like 10sec
   Close pc from power button. Insert RAM and battery

3)
   Insert usb stick to left port, plug ac power

Keep FN + ESC pressed and press power

The fan should start spinning faster now. I got **NO** other indication

I left it like this for a couple of minutes and then it shuts down on it's own

Then i started it and voila it was working.

Might need try last step a couple of times till u get it correct